# Why cdc_ether network device is not being observed by udev?

Tags: linux, usb, udev, network-interface

Why a network interface appears without udev knowing about it?

```
# rnn ip link show dev usb0
Device "usb0" does not exist.
# stdbuf -oL udevadm monitor -p  | grep 'SUBSYSTEM\|ACTION\|e2:c9:f6:5c:37:7c' --line-buffered
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=usb
^C
# rnn ip link show dev usb0
35: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:c9:f6:5c:37:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I expect `SUBSYSTEM=net` events, as new network interface `usb0` appeared. How do I make udev handle it?

Meanwhile `systemd-udevd --debug` shows network-related messages:

```
seq 9553 queued, 'add' 'usb'
seq 9554 queued, 'add' 'usb'
seq 9555 queued, 'add' 'net'
seq 9556 queued, 'add' 'queues'
seq 9557 queued, 'add' 'queues'
seq 9558 queued, 'add' 'usb'
...
PROGRAM '/bin/readlink /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules' /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules:6
```

Comment: One step: `udevadm` should be running in the same network namespace where the interface appears.

Comment: Can we make a more direct comparison.  If I run `udevadm info -p /class/net/wlan0` it shows `E: SUBSYSTEM=net`.  That happens for you (for the usb0 device) - right?  If so, we're asking why isn't that shown in udevadm monitor?

Comment: Maybe @Vi knows, but my Fedora 24 doesn't know what `rnn` is.  What is the significance of `rnn`?  The commands seem to work for me if I remove `rnn`.

Comment: `rnn` (root network namespace) is a private script that runs commands in other network namespace

Comment: I would replace `rnn` with `nsenter -n -p 1` or define it as such (unless it does more magic to escape PID namespace?).  Public reports are much more useful if they can be reproduced.  (And doubly so if they can outline reasoning, applicability.  I haven't seen user sessions run in nn, so it's a puzzle to me why you get in this situation to start with).

Comment: @sourcejedi, `nsenter -n` (without `-p`) may work here, but only for root. `rnn` can also allow particular non-admin user to enter particular namespace.

Comment: how is this information useful to me, I don't have your private `rnn`, and it is not relevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `udevd` running not on the root [network namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) (where network adapters added by default).

Additionally `udevadm monitor`'s network namespace also affects its output.

Comment: The question implies both `udevadm monitor` and `systemd-udevd --debug` were run in the same way (same namespace), yet gave different results.  Maybe you missed an `rnn`.